# Standardize image into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Bootstrap and I want to put some photos into my div and I want them to be all at the same size ("standardize").

If they're too big (and they will always be) **I want to resize them to fit in my div and crop them if necessary**.

*For the moment her is what I do :*

I've tried to change the style of the image in jQuery in a function:

*• If the height is bigger than the width, I switch the style to max-width:100% and height auto.*

*• Inversement if the width is bigger than the height.*

But I'm still new to jQuery and I am probably doing something wrong; can someone light my lantern please?

**Here is my jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  photoResize();
  $(window).resize(function(){
    photoResize();
  });   
});

function photoResize(){
  image_w = $('img').width();
  image_h = $('img').height();

  if(image_h > image_w)
  {
    $('img').css("max-width","100%");
    $('img').height("auto");
  } 
  else if(image_w > image_h)
  {
    $('img').css("max-height","100%");
    $('img').width("auto");         
  } 
}
```

And here is a Fiddle for a better view : https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/DTcHh/9801/

Comment: `img` is not defined anywhere in your code

Comment: why js if you can do it with css? https://jsfiddle.net/47swyp7k/

Comment: Hum, shall I specifie the img by an id like "test" and try to select them like this ? $("#test").xxx

Comment: also, setting width/height to 100% wont work if the parent element doesnt have a demention to contain it (you'd div's have no width so are 100% by default (block level))

Comment: On your jsfiddle, the img style is missing the semi-colon on the max-width declaration.  Just setting that makes them fit the width of the container.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida No I can't do this because the image are loosing they orignal ratio, i dont want them to lose their shape, i just want them to fit into div and the only possibility is to crop them (this is why I use overflow:hidden)

Comment: @Baldrani: Why you are not creating thumbnails of each image and show them into div? It will not affect the ratio of the image. And process also standardized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simplicity

I do this quite often in the CMS we use at work for galleries etc. The method I use involves a jQuery library called imgLiquid.js.

This will turn an inline image into a background image on the parent div. It's good because you can achieve your desired effect. It will crop the image (as it technically becomes a background image) and will apply `background-size: cover;` and `background-position: center center;` as inline styles.

[You can find the plugin here](https://github.com/karacas/imgLiquid)

To initialize the plugin you just need:

```
$(".myele").imgLiquid();
```

### Overheads

The plugin is very small (roughly around 5.106 KB) so you don't need to worry about adding weight to the page. It really it the most simple method I've come across (bar using thumbnails generated from the sever-side - see note at  the bottom).

#### Cue CSS

I've tested this thoroughly and found it gives excellent results. You may then ask... what happens to my parent divs (as technically the plugin hides the img element - which therefore means the parent element doesn't know what height to make itself).

An easy method to make things work responsively, or not:

```
.myelement:before{
    content: "";
    padding-top: 50%;
    display: block;
}
```

This CSS will give your heights back to the wrapping element. So if you wanted certain proportions you could use this math:

h / w * 100 = your percentage for the padding-top.

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/qulaye/edit?html,css,js,output)

#### Small note

Technically if I had the control I'd advise just using thumbnails.. I assume you're using some sort of system that could technically just render cut down versions of the images? The reason I use this method — and suggested it — is that I don't have control over the CMS and I'm assuming you just want to manage the code that's being produced as it's not stated.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, I tried it and tell you if it is working for me :)

Comment: No problems. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Please remember if you choose to use this method to make sure you accept as the answer

Comment: Thank you ! I've tested it on their site and this is exactly what I was looking for :) 
Just have to implement this into mine now.
I let you know if I've got problem but this should be perfect.

Great answer ! Thx again.

Comment: Ok So i've tried it it work efficiently but I still have a little problem I dont understand how you've manage to keep the height of your parent element unchange.
See what I got :/ --> http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=803371Capturedcran20150710114609.png

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code, but have you made sure the `:before` is placed on the element wrapping the image and you've removed any height based CSS?

Comment: Humm yeah, well I'l see what I can do; I assume it's due to the theme i'm using. Let play the wizard a bit. I tell you if I'm succesfull.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make your images the same size then you dont need any javascript or calculations, why not just set it in css?

```
.someUniqueContainer img{
  width:300px;
  height:300px; // or what ever height you want
}
```

I'm guessing that in reality you actually want to crop all your images to a set width/height. if that's the case you'll need a serverside script for that.

where are the images coming from? it would be easyer to just edit them. if they are coming from a user then you would resize/crop on the server on file upload

Comment: Its an intern serveur of the society I'm in; I can't modify them all they are too many.

Comment: you wouldnt have to do it manually, depending on the server/language ect you could run a script on all images in a directory and get them cropped (so if say you where using php you could write a script using [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php) and run it aon all images in one go

Comment: Yeah but because it is a responsiv design i cannot afford to have duplication of every image I have. The answer has been post just over there by @Mat-visual

Answer (score 0):

There were several mistakes in your code.
Please look at this jsfiddle, please see https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9796/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     photoResize();

     $(window).resize(function () {
         photoResize();
     });
 });

 function photoResize() {
     image_w = $('img').width();
     image_h = $('img').height();

     if (image_h > image_w) {
         $('img').css("max-width", "100%");
         $('img').height("auto");
     } else if (image_w > image_h) {
         $('img').css("max-height", "100%");
         $('img').width("auto");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Looking at the example it doesn't quite work. Your example needs this CSS: `img
{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}`

Answer (score 0):

sth like this?, although this is pure css, not jquery included, might not be suit in your case..

```
body {
margin-top:20px
}
.col-xs-3 {
margin: 5px 0;
width: 500px;
height:120px
}
.col-xs-3 > div {
width: 100%;
height: 120px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9800/)

Comment: Nup, this change the shape of the photo too

Comment: to remain the proportion, maybe use background-size: contain, if with img tag, then use width 100%, height auto. or set max-width: 100% and max-height. some combination like this