# Responsive Image of same height keeping their Ratio

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm facing a problem that seems to be unresolved unless I just have not found the answer (It was not in the "Questions that may already have your answer" neither did I found it accros the Web).

So Here is my problem :
I have multiple image never the same height/width but I want them to be displayed with the same aspect and keeping their ratio.
Concretely what I'm trying to respect is :

- **Same Height/Width**
- **Same Ratio (no deformation)**
- **Responsive**
- **Full-fill the container**
- **Cropped to full-fill**
- **Center**

Like this but in responsive : [image: Example]

Here is a Fiddle of what I have found for now on : **[my excavation](http://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/4oc6mjs1/1/)**

### CSS :

This is for keeping the same ratio.

```
height: 50%;
width: auto;
```

And this is to ajust to the size I want (But this is not responsive !)

```
   position: relative ;
    float: left;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
```

I'm open to every solution; jQuery as well.

Comment: Change height: 200px to max-height: 200px (or a greater value, like 500px) and change width: 200px to max-width: 100%. Is this the effect you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/Screetop/4oc6mjs1/

Comment: @MathijsRutgers Yes and No; It respect a part of the idea but it it not full-filling the container. I have updated my fiddle to better comprehension

Comment: This should help you sir: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336306/standardize-image-into-div/31336568#31336568

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue which often happens in frontend development. Ideally we should use images which have the exact same size so that the aspect ratios remain the same.

When the images have verying heights then we need to crop the images somehow so that they have the same height.

Here is an [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vu1n4ex8/) example of what you can do.

```
.image-wrap {
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 0;
   padding-bottom: 50%;
}
.image-wrap img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Wrap the image in a div with `overflow: hidden` and use padding bottom to define the height of the image.

Comment: Beautiful !! You sir deserve my respect !

Comment: Neat little bit of styling there

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has been adding CSS to your ".container" element.
This is what I got by overwriting some of the elements in your code:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 81pt;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:0px;
}
.productImage {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

[Here is your updated code on **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4oc6mjs1/2/)