# How to stretch and image in a responsive website in CSS

Tags: css, slideshow, image-resizing, autoresize

I have a series of images in a slide show, which have all be uploaded at different image dimensions, I want to essentially make all the images follow a rule whereby they stretch, proportionally to the max width so that if you resize the browser window, they will still keep their fluid resizing response also.

[Here](http://www.andymoller.com/Roksanda-AW15) is the website template and the images in question.

Would love to be able to do it in CSS if possible.

I'm having trouble stretching small images to fit into a larger container, rather than trying to contain large images in a small container. Usually the smaller image stops resizing once it's hit its actual pixel dims and I want them to continue to stretch proportionally, even if this pixelates them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image resize to fit screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569192/image-resize-to-fit-screen)

Comment: Possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569192/image-resize-to-fit-screen

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336306/standardize-image-into-div/31336568#31336568 — there really is a tone of questions on this thing if you try the search.

Comment: thanks Mat and Marcos, i will re-look at these solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The key to solving this is using background images and their CSS properties. Rather than inserting the images as `<img>` tags you should create containers with a background image set

`<div class="slide" style="background-image: url(image1.jpg)"></div>`

Give those containers some styling so they fill out your slideshow area.

`position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;`

Then you can use `background-size: contain;` to make the image sit within the containers using pure CSS. It'll never extend outside of the area, but will fill it as much as possible. Also use `background-position: center;` and turn off image repeat using `background-repeat: no-repeat;` - then you'll have a single image centred and as large as it can be.

Full CSS is as follows:

`position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
display: block; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;`

You'll be able to use CSS transitions to control how the slideshow moves between slides.

Comment: Thanks Henry, I'll give it a go and let you know.